# Calling external method from runnable task.

Tags: java, multithreading

I have waitandsweep method in which I create a runnable task and schedule it using threadpoolexecutor. From runnable task I am calling external method isSliceDone() eventhough the value is true, it is not honouring it. meaning the control is going to next else if part. I think there is some synchronization issue here. Can someone help pls ?

```
    protected void waitAndSweep(final String symbol) {
        try {

          runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              try {

              if (isSliceDone()) {
                  long timeSinceLastSliceQtySent = lastSliceSentTime == 0 ? getInterval() : System.currentTimeMillis() - lastSliceSentTime;
                  long waitTime = timeSinceLastSliceQtySent >= getInterval() ? 0 : getInterval() - timeSinceLastSliceQtySent;

                  if (waitTime > 0) {
                    logTradeEvent("waitAndSweep", symbol, "waittime: " + waitTime);
                    Thread.sleep(waitTime);
                  }
                } else if (sweepInterval > 0) {
// It always comes here eventhough isSliceDone is true.
                  logTradeEvent("waitAndSweep", symbol, "sweepInterval: " + sweepInterval);
                  Thread.sleep(sweepInterval);
                }

                callSweep(symbol);
              } catch (Exception e) {

              }
            }
          };

          Future<?> self = threadPoolExecutor.submit(runnable);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
      }



 private boolean isSliceDone() {

    synchronized (this) {
      double sliceQuantity = getSliceQuantity();

      if (Quant.equals(sentSliceQty % sliceQuantity, 0.0) && Quant.equals(executedSliceQty % sliceQuantity, 0.0)) {

        return Quant.greater(sentSliceQty, executedSliceQty) ? false : true;
      }
      return false;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `isSliceDone()` actually returns true when you expect it? Check it by storing it in a boolean variable, logging that value and use the value in the if statement.

Comment: For the same input, when i debug step by step it is logged as true else as false.. Isnt it some sync issue?

Comment: The runnable you submit only runs through once. If the first time the `isSliceDone()` is false you end up in the else if statement or the code after. So unless `callSweep()` pushes the the same runnable on the pool again you only run through the code once, the `Thread.sleep statement do nothing but delay the execution of the next instruction. You will want to use a while loop.

Comment: Is "isSliceDone" accessing some field for checking your condition? In this case, you have to declare the field "volatile" if this field is changed by another thread.